# Angular-gantt | Filter tasks - make it shows only rows with filtered task?

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart

https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/

As you can see on this website, if you filter Task, then it hides only other tasks.

How can I make it to shows only rows with filtered tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Use filter-row attribute, put your filter function inside controler and here 'reverse' your logic. The row will be visible if filter-function will return this row, otherwise not.
Here's an example:

```
$scope.calendarFilter = function(row, $index) {

  if ($scope.calendar.filter == 'all') {
    return row;
  } else {
    if ($scope.calendar.filter.id == row.model.typeId ) {
      return row;
    }
  }
```

};

[Source here](https://www.angular-gantt.com/configuration/attributes/#filter-row-filter-row-comparator)